# Totalling times in HHMM format

Tags: java

So i have a series of times:

```
ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();
times.add("1240");
times.add("1028");
times.add("0923");
times.add("2023");
```

And I wan't to find the total hours traversed between these times, but I can't figure out how!

For example:

> "1240 to 1028" would be 11hrs20 + 10hrs28 in travel time.
>
> To go from 12h40 on one day to 10h28 next day, you need 11h20 (going to midnight), then 10h28. Quite clear.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how you calculate the "total hours traversed between these times"? It's unclear how you derive "11hrs20 + 10hrs28 in travel time." from "1240 to 1028".

Comment: To go from 12h40 on one day to 10h28 next day, you need 11h20 (going to midnight), then 10h28. Quite clear.

Comment: @MateoBarahona thanks for clearing that up haha ^^

Comment: Wich version of java do you use ? Have access to joda time ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need a way to convert a string into a linear time representation:

```
// Given a string of the form HHMM, this returns the number of minutes after midnight.
// For example: timeStringToMinutes("0000") -> 0.
// timeStringToMinutes("0015") -> 15.
// timeStringToMinutes("0100") -> 60.
// timeStringToMinutes("0837") -> 517.
// timeStringToMinutes("2359") -> 1439.
static int timeStringToMinutes(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2, 4));
}
```

Next we define a function to compute time differences:

```
// Example: forwardNumberOfMinutes("1240", "1028") -> 1308.
static int forwardNumberOfMinutes(String start, String end) {
    int from = timeStringToMinutes(start);
    int to   = timeStringToMinutes(end);
    if (to < from)
        to += 1440;  // 1 day, or 24 hours
    return to - from;
}
```

Finally we define a function to convert linear time to hours and minutes:

```
// Example: minutesToTimeString(1308) -> "2148" (21 hr 48 min).
static minutesToTimeString(int n) {
    return String.format("%02d%02d", n / 60, n % 60);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! But so I understand the code, why do you do:

`to += 1440;` to represent a day?

Comment: Suppose you have `start="2310"`and `end="0040"`. We calculate `from=1390` and `to=40`.

Comment: If we just calculate `to - from = -1350`, this is not what we want. So we advance `to` to the next day, at `to=1480`.

Comment: Now when we subtract, `to - from = 130`, which is the result we want. (90 minutes, or 1 hr 30 min.)

Comment: @madcrazydrumma 24 hours per day is 60*24 = 1440 minutes per day.

Comment: @lurker and nayuki thanks for explaining it to me ^^ helps a lot